# Opening images from 2 folders and displaying them simultaneously in python

Tags: python, tkinter

I would like to open images from 2 different folders and display them next to each other , also have a button " Next" to be able to move to the next pair of images.

The images paths are stored in a txt file , so lets say open the first image and the second image and when I click next , 3rd and 4th image and so on

I am new to python and this is what I found so far to read an image

```
from Tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
import os


root = Tk()

img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("path.ppm"))
panel = Label(root, image = img)
panel.pack(side = "bottom", fill = "both", expand = "yes")
root.mainloop()
```

But i can't figure how to open 2 images simultaneously and add the next button

Comment: Your question is almost broad; however as you seem to know already how to display one picture, for sure you can display 2 in the same time (just add an other label to hold it as you did for the first one, and read 2 lines from your text file at once)

Comment: have you tried simply duplicating the three lines before `root.mainloop()` to see what happens?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a working example of what you ask:

```
  from tkinter import *

  def UpdateImg ( ):
     global img1, img2
     img1 = PhotoImage(file=ImgFiles[Cur])
     img2 = PhotoImage(file=ImgFiles[Cur+1])

     LblImg1.configure(image = img1, text=ImgFiles[Cur])
     LblImg2.configure(image = img2, text=ImgFiles[Cur+1] )

  def BtnNext( ):
     global Cur
     if Cur < len(ImgFiles)-2:
        Cur = Cur  + 2
        UpdateImg ( )

  def BtnPrev( ):
     global Cur
     if Cur > 1:
        Cur = Cur  - 2
        UpdateImg ( )

  fp = open("ImgFilesSrc.txt", "r")
  ImgFiles = fp.read().split('\n')
  fp.close()

  Cur = 0
  img1 = img2 = ''
  root = Tk()

  #Create the main Frame -----------------------------------------------------------------
  FrmMain = Frame(root)
  LblImg1 = Label(FrmMain, text = "Picture 1",   anchor=W, width=120, bg="light sky blue")
  LblImg2 = Label(FrmMain, text = "Picture 2",   anchor=W, width=120, bg="light sky blue")

  BtnPrev  = Button(FrmMain, text=" <  ", width=10, command=BtnPrev)
  BtnNext  = Button(FrmMain, text="  > ", width=10, command=BtnNext)   

  LblImg1.grid (row=2, rowspan = 3, column=1, columnspan=3);
  LblImg2.grid (row=2, rowspan = 3, column=4, columnspan=3);

  BtnPrev.grid (row=5, column=2);   BtnNext.grid(row=5, column=4)

  FrmMain.pack(side=TOP, fill=X)     
  #--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  UpdateImg ( )
  root.mainloop()
```